# Design pattern for file reader?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am creating a module that reads CSV and Excel files using Apache POI and Opencsv.

For reading CSV files, I am creating 1 class and 2 methods:

```
class CsvReader {
  void open() {//implementation}
  List<CsvDto1> get1() {//implementation}
  List<CsvDto2> get2() {//implementation}
  void close() {//implementation}
}
```

For reading Excel files, I am also creating 1 class and 2 methods:

```
class ExcelReader {
  void open() {//implementation}
  List<ExlDto1> get3() {//implementation}
  List<ExlDto2> get4() {//implementation}
  void close() {//implementation}
}
```

All I want is to implement a pattern that will be helped maintainable in the future. So I created an interface called `FileReadable`:

```
interface FileReadable {
  void open();
  List<CsvDto1> get1()
  List<CsvDto2> get2()
  List<ExlDto1> get3()
  List<ExlDto2> get4()
  void close();
}
```

then `CsvReader` and `ExcelReader` will be implemented from `FileRedable`. The issue is `get1()` and `get2()` exist in `CsvReader` but they do not exist in `ExcelReader`, `get3()` and `get4()` exist in `ExcelReader` but they do not exist in `CsvReader`. How do I create a common `read` method for both classes or do we have any design pattern for this case?

```
   interface FileReadable {
      void open();
      Reader read();
      void close();
   }
```

Comment: Side note: if it has a `close()` method, you most probably want it to extend [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) to support [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 2):

From your question, I see that you have `Dto1` and `Dto2`. Prefixes `Csv` and `Exl` are part of implementation and should not be part of definition. You would need one interface called:

```
interface FileReadable {
  void open();
  List<Dto1> get1()
  List<Dto2> get2()
  void close();
}
```

And then your clients will not be aware or care if it comes from `Exl` or `Csv`. They will just use `Dto1` or `Dto2`. If you really need to know the origin, you can create property in `Dto` class that can have values like `EXCEL`, `CSV`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use generic interface:

```
interface FileReadable<T> {
  void open();
  List<CsvDto1> get1();
  List<CsvDto2> get2();
  void close();
}
```

And just implement this interface in appropriate classes.

[Read more about generic interface here in this nice post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623480/generic-interface)

Answer (score 1):

Strategy pattern is the best.

i usually write like this:

```
public interface FileReadable {
    String getFileType();
    void open();
    Reader read();
    void close();
}

@Service
public class Csv1File implements FileReadable{
    @Override
    public String getFileType() {
        return "csv1";
    }

    @Override
    public void open() {

    }

    @Override
    public Reader read() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

use like this

```
    @Resource
    List<FileReadable> fileReadable;

    String file = "csv1";
        Optional<FileReadable> first = fileReadable.stream().filter(read -> Objects.equals(file, read.getFileType())).findFirst();
        if (first.isPresent()) {
            first.get().read();
        }
```

you can also create like Csv2File.class Excel1File.class and use `getFileType()` to mark this class is support which kind of file.